# Target a specific version of Android with Meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

*Yes, I have read the [Meteor Cordova PhoneGap Integration Guide](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#configuring-android-virtual-devices) but I couldn't find any information on this issue.*

I am trying to set up Meteor to develop for Android.
My phone runs Android 4.2.*something* and a lot of our potential users probably run some JellyBean (4.1.*x*-4.3.*x*), ICS (4.0.*x*) or Gingerbread (2.3.*x*) - but probably not KitKat (4.4.*x*).

Meteor by default targets only android-19 (4.4.x), un-installing this target even makes it think that the ADK is not installed at all. (I used `meteor configure-android` for that, which appearantly only configures the ADK and not Meteor itself.)

How can I make both my emulator and my builds target older/different versions of Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit outdated but if anyone else runs into this this same question, The answer by Mário is valid, but if like myself one does not use Android Studio this can also help.

Add this line to your `mobile-config.js`:

`App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '17');`

replace 17 with your desired version.

This might also help: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3434#issuecomment-97953738

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in mobile-config.js.So no need to struggle with android studio.

```
App.setPreference('android-minSdkVersion', '14');**
App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '23');
App.setPreference('android-versionCode', '3');**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Eclipse or Android Studio. I had a similar issue with the iOS version. It's using the iOS 8 and with this SDK the iPhone 4 is not supported. So in my case, I opened the generated project file and changed it to iOS 7 SDK.

I'm not an Android Developer but the process should very very similar I guess.